# Content not showing on PHP include?

Tags: php, html, include

I've run into the most bizzare problem. 
A PHP include calls in a file, which contains the beginning of the body tag as well as the beginning of the main tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="sidebar">

  </div>

  <div id="main">

<div id="menu">
    <p> test test test </p>
</div>
```

The strange thing is, the elements show up no problem but that test message doesn't. It's not hidden under any elements, because when I view the source it's still not there. I have a feeling this is something really dumb/trivial, but it's got me stumped.

Here's my php:

```
<?php 
include 'inc/header.php';
require_once 'login.php';
echo('<div class="somespace"></div>');
include 'inc/queries.php';
include 'inc/footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: What does your PHP look like?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't show up in the source?  My initial guess was that you have a style in your `css/style.css` stylesheet that was hiding the text.  Either way, you'll need to give a lot more information here.  Like what's in all the other files, what's in the stylesheet, and so on.

Comment: do you get any PHP errors in your PHP error log file?

Comment: @drrcknlsn I'm positive. Nothing in the files influences the menu tag. login.php contains my db login details and queries contains some functions that fetch some content into main div.

Comment: @Jocelyn I'll check in a bit.

Comment: off topic, but there are much better ways to template your site than this.

Comment: @SDC I'm only learning so I'm not familiar with other methods. If you could sure I'd be grateful :)

Comment: @Megh: PHP simply dumps its output buffer to the browser, and markup from an included file is dumped as-is.  That means that if you aren't seeing what you expect to see in the browser source, then something in your scripts **is** influencing the markup, whether you're aware of it or not.  That, or it really is in the source, and you just missed it for whatever reason.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work fine, so in conclusion:

It's simple: your hdd, local/hosted drive has encountered on write process a delay writing error

you see your code in the file, but in reality, its not there

if using filezilla, close and connect again, and see whats there

please give more info for the storage machine

i had the same problem on bluehost.com with theyr drives (HDDs)

Comment: I did copy&paste my xampp onto a different machine because my old one failed. It seems to have more of an effect than I'd anticipated, because this isn't the only problem I've encountered.

Comment: so, what was the error ? or, does it work now ? if not, upload the files somewhere, give link, and i will return code